# UITableView: How to get heightForHeaderInSection inside viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a custom section header view for my `UITableView`.

But how do I get the tableHeight in my `viewForHeaderInSection` method? I am currently doing the below and `tableHeight` holds the value 0.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (includeButton)
        return 55;
    else
        return 30;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat tableHeight = [tableView headerViewForSection:section].frame.size.height;
    ........
}
```

Comment: What return zero? In the method viewForHeaderInSection you must return the view for such section, so if you can't get the header of the section because in that method you must create the header.

Comment: You should use one variable to hold value of height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods are in the same view controller. Just call your implementation and pass the table view and section, like so:

```
CGFloat tableHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your table header section height based on

```
if (includeButton)
    return 55;
else
    return 30;
```

Similarly, you can do the same when you want to get the section height.

```
 CGFloat tableHeight = (includeButton)?55:30;
```

But you have to make sure that the "includeButton" exist for each section.

Hope that helps.